# How can I configure Spring Cache to ignore cache serialization errors?

Tags: java, spring, caching

I'm using Spring Cache with Redis / JDK Serialization as cache backend. I have a method whose result is cached and the cache is populated with some values. In an update to my app, I'm changing the class of the cached object in a way that breaks Java deserialization (changing the type of a member from a `List` to a `Set`). Now any invokation to my cached method fails with `org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException`.

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "myCache", cacheManager = "myCacheManager)
public SomeObject myCachedMethod(String param) {
    return ...;
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot deserialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.util.ArrayList to field SomeObject.foo of type java.util.Set in instance of SomeObject
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.deserialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:41) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache$CacheValueAccessor.deserializeIfNecessary(RedisCache.java:378) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.get(RedisCache.java:144) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.get(RedisCache.java:94) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doGet(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:68) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findInCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:466) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:432) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:336) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:302) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy175.myCachedMethod(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Is there a way to configure Spring cache to ignore error when deserializing objects and let the method invokation go through?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found a solution after reading through Spring's code.

Cache layer handling happens in an instance of `org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheErrorHandler`. By default, Spring uses `org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleCacheErrorHandler` which throws back all exceptions. To relax this, one can extend that class and log / ignore cache get exceptions (which causes them to be handled like cache miss):

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfiguration extends CachingConfigurerSupport {
    @Slf4j
    private static class RelaxedCacheErrorHandler extends SimpleCacheErrorHandler {
        @Override
        public void handleCacheGetError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
            log.error("Error getting from cache.", exception);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        return new RelaxedCacheErrorHandler();
    }

    // More config...
}
```

Comment: Would be nice if after prevent the error some kind of circuit breaker mechanisc were triggered. Because if there are too many calls to the cached method, all responses would take at least the timeout of Redis connection plus the actual work to get the data. I was trying to find some way to do this but I did not have much success.